# Allow list views based on getting a users group via a Get User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-foundation, list-view

Is there away to hide views based on a usergroup using JavaScript?  At first we had one List and created views for each section.  Now we only want the individual views shown only if a visitor belongs to a certain group.  I understand that if we use a GetUserId method we can get their id.  Is there away to get the group then make certain views display based on Group?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a blank Page and then add a a list view web part to display a specific view of your list. Make this web part only visible for a certain group using Advanced-->Target Audiences from the web part properties. Repeat these steps for all views.